# Are there solutions to $x^2 = 171\pmod{203}$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

The question is: Give any two solutions $x^2 = 171\pmod{203}$. I am pretty sure this is no solution but I am not sure. How would I go about writing a proof to show there are no solutions for my homework?

Comment: You are correct, that has no solutions. Even  $x^2\equiv 171 \pmod 7$ doesn't  have any solutions (that's easy to write up and it suffices).

Comment: You can't have 171 ( mod 7) can you? 171 > 7 @lulu

Comment: Sure you can.  $171\equiv 3 \pmod 7 $ so asking to solve $x^2\equiv 171\pmod 7$ is the same as asking to solve $x^2\equiv 3 \pmod 7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Consider the quadratic residues $\mod 7$.

---

Let $a\equiv 0\mod 7$. Then
$$a^2\equiv 0^2\equiv0\mod 7$$
$$(a+1)^2\equiv 1^2\equiv1\mod 7$$
$$(a+2)^2\equiv 2^2\equiv 4\mod 7$$
$$(a+3)^2\equiv 3^2\equiv2\mod 7$$
$$(a+4)^2\equiv 4^2\equiv2\mod 7$$
$$(a+5)^2\equiv 5^2\equiv4\mod 7$$
$$(a+6)^2\equiv 6^2\equiv1\mod 7$$
Now since $171\equiv 3\mod 7$, it's impossible that some $x$ satisfy $x^2\equiv 171 \mod 7$ (note that all possilbe quadratic residues are from the set $\{0, 1, 2, 4\}$, which doesn't contain $\{3\}$).

Hence, you won't find any integer $x$ either such that $171\equiv x^2\mod 203\iff 171\equiv x^2\mod (\color{red}{7}·29)$